# Why @ExceptionHandler(value = Throwable.class) doesn't catch OutOfMemoryError?

Tags: java, spring, exception, out-of-memory

I have the global application handler in my spring mvc application:

```
@ExceptionHandler(value = Throwable.class)
public ModelAndView redirectToErrorPage(Exception e) {
   ...
}
```

In place#1 I write following code:

```
@Override
public void save(Content content, MultipartFile multipartFile) {
    if (true) {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}
```

after throw RuntimeException program execution goes to method `redirectToErrorPage`

If to replace

```
throw new RuntimeException()
```

with

```
throw new OutOfMemoryError()
```

then program execution doesn't go over to the `redirectToErrorPage` method.

Why?

Comment: Why are you trying to catch an `OutOfMemoryError`?

Comment: Cause Error is not an Exception

Comment: @ Alex K. but Error is Throwable

Comment: @Vivin Paliath Tester found bug that if to pass  a huge content then user sees stacktrace. expected result - error page.   redirect to error page has written in exceptionHandler

Comment: But your redirectToErrorPage takes Exception as an argument.

Comment: @gstackoverflow Instead of catching the OOME, why don't you set limits on  the request-body size?

Comment: @VivinPaliath is correct. An OOME is going to leave the JVM in an inconsistent state where it isn't likely that your application would be able to do anything useful from that point on. There isn't really anything you can do expect restart the JVM.

Comment: I want to avoid to show stacktrace to clients

Comment: @gstackoverflow That's exactly what you will be able to do if you set limits on the size of the request-body.